# Move cursor from surrounds

Tags: cursor-movement, insert-mode

What is best way to move cursor from the inside surrounds `'"([{` (and other types)?

For example, I'm typing `if (condition) { body }`. I've typed the `condition`, then I should go to `body`.

For me it's very annoying to `esc`, move cursor, go to insert `mode`

Comment: One way is to use a snippet system (Ultisnips, Neosnippet <- plugins) and use/define an `if` snippet that has placeholders for `condition` and `body`, placeholders that can be edited and jumped from one to the another. Other than that, in Vim there are many ways to quickly "move cursor" with precision to a desired location.

Comment: It's not about snippet system, just go out of brackets and continue typing.

Comment: That where snippets and abbreviations with placeholders come in handy. You just hit `tab`, `CTRL-J` or whatever the plugin/placeholder system uses and you'll be doing all those tasks at once: `<esc>/{<cr>o`. The downside is that you need abbreviations or snippets for all the control statements you could use. Fortunately, C control statements are well spread. I even have a for-range loop for C++ in lh-cpp. If some part of the body has already been typed, well, you'll need to define a mapping to do what you wish.

Comment: You simply use your cursor keys.

Comment: If you find it annoying maybe you don't move your cursor efficiently: how do you move it? Here after typing `condition` you can do `<Esc>f{a` which isn't that bad... Now if you really want to cut some keystrokes the plugin solution seems pretty good.

Comment: I would use `<C-o>` which let you execute a normal command before returning in insert mode: `<C-o>fb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start from this map (and improve it according to your taste):

```
inoremap <C-x><C-x> <Esc>/[[({,]\_s*/e<CR>a
```

.. which maps `Ctrl-x Ctrl-x` in insert mode to jump after a set of characters (open brackets, I added comma since it could be useful also to jump over function arguments), skipping also any white spaces or newlines that follow. So, if the text is written, just hit `Ctrl-x Ctrl-x` to move to the 'next' position, until the cursor is where you want it. How you then change the code that follows is your decision.

[image]